# What to do if HTTP TRACE request has body?

Tags: http

I'm implementing a special-purpose HTTP server, and have stumbled across a scenario where I can't work out what the RFC wants me to do.  Clients MUST NOT send a TRACE request with a body (cf Section 9.8).  But if a client sends a body-related header in a TRACE request (i.e. a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header), I seem to have two options for how to make the server behave:

1. Read the illegal body and ignore it
2. Treat the headers the same as a client would treat the response to a HEAD method, i.e. as information about a body that hasn't been included, and assume therefore that there is no body.

I don't see anything in the RFC that favours either solution.  So, which should I take?  Is there another alternative I haven't seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the body, and then either ignore it, or return a 4xx status code. See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/19.

Comment: A message body on TRACE isn't the same as on GET -- the RFC merely doesn't say what should be done with a body on a GET request, but specifically states that a TRACE request must not have one.

Comment: Yes. It's a client bug. But if you want to keep the connection open, you'll need to consume the payload. You can then ignore it, or signal the client error.